TLS 1.3 application not launching while recording in Neoload
I am trying to record an application with TLSv1.3. The issue is that when I try to record the workflow using Neoload  script recorder, it does not launch the application. Neoload just try to navigate to the application's URL and gives timeout after some time. When I normally try to navigate to the same web application, it is working fine. I have tried it with different browsers using Neoload v8.0 and the latest Neoload v2024. I also tried using tunnel mode to record application's workflow but it doesn't detect the port correctly.
How can I overcome this issue and record the application's workflow?
